# Enviar email para cliente para verificar se existe ou não

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, envio-de-email

Eu fiz um cadastro pra ser inserido o cpf e email, o cpf eu consegui validar certinho, pra ver se funciona ou não. Porém quando chega a parte de saber se o email existe...pesquisei muito e vi uma forma, que é enviar um email pro usuário, e se o email for enviado, ou seja, nao voltar, ele existe. Porém não faço ideia como fazer isso, alguem pode me dar uma luz?

Comment: Considere usar um serviço que verifique o e-mail para você, segue um como exemplo: https://github.com/overint/php-mailgun-validation

Comment: tentou PHPMAILER ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para verificar se um email existe, é necessário criar um passo a mais no seu cadastro. Quando o usuário fizer o cadastro, registre seu status como "pendente" ou algo do tipo, e mande um email de confirmação para o endereço informado. O email deve conter um link único daquele usuário, como um hash do email informado + algum valor arbitrário como salt.

Quando o usuário acessar o link (que aponta para o seu sistema), você verifica o hash passado, e atualiza o status para "cadastrado".

Comment: te ajudou @NazareLisboa ?

Comment: @NazareLisboa Até porque não adianta simplesmente saber se o e-mail foi enviado e recebido, você precisa se certificar de que o endereço está correto e o usuário que fez o cadastro tem acesso a essa conta... caso contrário você não garante que ele receberá suas mensagens por esse canal no futuro. Se isso não é importante, não tem porque se preocupar com essa validação.

Comment: Isso é de suma importância @LeandroAngelo

Comment: Me esclareceu muita coisa. Mas queria fazer uma pergunta: eu preciso criar um servidor só pro emails dos usuários? um amigo meu disse que eu preciso, mas acho que não seria pra tanto @JulioHenrique97

Comment: @NazareLisboa geralmente não, isso depende do volume de dados que você vai estar trabalhando.

Comment: ao inves de https://www.sitedanazarelisboa.com.br fica localhost:8080/site/index.php Por exemplo

Comment: no caso poderei botar assim: localhost:8080/site/  ?

Comment: Eu coloquei e funcionou, só que dá o seguinte erro: Erro no envio do e-mailSMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting